Where am I allowed to post a link to a website selling Lego compatible bricks?
I am curious if I am allowed to post a website (Lego compatible store) link here.

This is covered in the FAQ on promotion aka "How to not be a spammer". But basically : no, unless it's directly relevant to (a part of) an answer of yours.

I’m voting to close this question because it is soliciting to promote an alternative website

As others have mentioned, unless it's directly relevant to a question, and you disclose your relationship with the site, you can't promote other sites in answers.
You can however add a link to the site in your profile, either in the "About Me" section or in the "Links" section. Both of which will allow you to promote your site:


If it's in answer to someone's question, and you disclose that it's your own site, then yes. Otherwise, I think, no.
